# Gluing along a finite morphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose $C_0$ is a dense open subvariety of $C$ and $C_0 \rightarrow D_0$ is a finite morphism.  Does there exist a finite morphism $C \rightarrow D$ to some other variety $D$ that agrees with $C_0 \rightarrow D_0$ on $C_0$?

I know this is possible if $C_0$ is closed, and that there are counterexamples in general.  I'm looking for certain situations where such a morphism might exist.

Comment: Denote the degree of $C_0\to D_0$ by $d$.  Form the fiber product $C_0\times_{D_0} C_0$ as a locally closed subscheme of $C\times_{\text{Spec}\ k} C$ (I assume that we are working over a field $k$).  If the closure $Z$ of $C_0\times_{D_0} C_0$ is finite and flat with respect to the projection $\text{pr}_1:Z\to C$, then you can construct the morphism $C\to D$ as the associated morphism to the Hilbert scheme of $C$, $\zeta_Z:C\to \text{Hilb}^d_{C/k}$, where $D$ is the image of $\zeta_Z$.  If $Z$ is just a "well-formed zero cycle", use the Chow variety instead of the Hilbert scheme.

Answer (score 1):

I am just posting my comment as an answer.  I will assume that we are working over a specified field $k$.  I will also assume that $C$ is reduced, irreducible, normal, and proper.  In the general case, you can first ask your question for the normalizations of the irreducible components of a proper model, and then you can try to descend from that normal, proper scheme to your original scheme.

The fiber product $Z_0 =C_0\times_{D_0} C_0$, considered as a closed subscheme of $C_0\times_{\text{Spec}\ k} C$, is a well-formed zero cycle of some degree $d$.  There is an induced morphism $\zeta_{Z_0}:C_0\to \text{Sym}^d_k(C)$.  There is an extension of $C_0\to D_0$ to a finite morphism with domain equal to $C$ if and only if $\zeta_{Z_0}$ extends to all of $C$.  In turn, this holds if and only if the closure $Z$ of $Z_0$ in $C\times_{\text{Spec}\ k} C$ is finite with respect to the projection $\text{pr}_1:Z\to C$.

The articles of David Rydh are a great source for Chow varieties.

Comment: This is very helpful.  Thank you.  How though can one arrange that the projection is finite on $Z$?  It seems to be the same problem as at the start, where the morphism on some open subvariety is finite.

Comment: I should mention that I include a variety $D'$ such that $C \rightarrow D'$ is projective but not finite, and that $D_0$ is open in $D'$.

Comment: @JeremyBerquist. "How though can one arrange that the projection is finite on $Z$?"  I am not certain what you are asking.  Do you want an example?  Do you want a counterexample?  Do you want sufficient conditions so that $Z$ is finite over $C$?  If you assume that $C$ is locally $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial and that the complement of $C_0$ in $C$ has codimension $2$ (as can be always arranged), then if there exists  an ample $\mathcal{A}$ on $\text{Sym}^d_k(C)$ with $\zeta_{Z_0}^*\mathcal{A}$ globally generated, then $Z\to C$ is finite.  Is that useful to you?

Comment: @JeremyBerquist. "I should mention that I include a variety $D'$ such that $C\to D'$ is projective but not finite, and that $D_0$ is open in $D'$."  On its own, that does not help.  There are such examples where $Z$ is finite over $C$, but there are also examples where $Z$ is not finite over $C$.  For instance, let $D'$ be the affine plane, let $Y\to D'$ be a finite, flat morphism of degree $2$ that is etale over the origin, and let $X\to Y$ be the blowing up of one of the two preimages of the origin.

Comment: Can you give a nontrivial example in which the induced morphism is finite?

Comment: @JeremyBerquist. "Can you give a nontrivial example in which the induced morphism is finite?"  Yes, yes I can.  However, since you are the one who proposed the original example, *you* should specify the example you would like to understand rather than asking me to list examples that (likely) have nothing to do with your examples.

Comment: Ok.  Here's what I've been working on.  A variety and its normalization are given, say $Y \rightarrow X$.  The map on conductor loci is $C \rightarrow D$.  On suitable open sets $X$ is semismooth and its normalization is smooth.  On these open sets $C \rightarrow D$ reduces to $C_0 \rightarrow D_0$, which is a smooth double cover of smooth varieties ramified along the pinch locus.  Then I do some blowups on $Y.$. The birational transform of $C$ contains $C_0$.  I  try for a finite morphism from the birational transform of $C$ to some other variety that agrees with $C_0 \rightarrow D_0$.

Comment: @JeremyBerquist. "Ok. Here's what I've been working on ..."  The answer really depends on the sequence of blowups on $Y$.  The example I mentioned above -- blowing up one of the two preimages of the origin -- can be one of the examples you mention.  At the least, you need to check that the sequence of blowups is equivariant for the cyclic group of order $2$ that exchanges the two "branches" of $C_0\to D_0$.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This last example you mention has been the source of my problems.  I don't know how to do the blowups in an equivariant way.  The exceptional divisor and preimage of the other point can't be exchanged by a finite group operation.